Upgrading Android API Level for Flutter App
I recently got a warning in the Google Play Console that my API level is too low for my Flutter app.
Deadline: Aug 30, 2024
Violation: App must target Android 14 (API level 34) or higher
When I look in /android/app/build.gradle I have these default settings related to my API version:
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "..."
    minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}

Where do flutter.minSdkVersion and flutter.targetSdkVersion get set? I consulted these docs and didn't find anything. My first thought is that it would be in pubspec.yaml, but I've never had anything related to the Android API version in there.
Do I have to manually set the values, or is there a way to set it via a Flutter configuration?
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "..."
    minSdkVersion 14 //<-- Set manually
    targetSdkVersion 34 //<-- Set manually
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true
}


Any progress on this?

I don't have a source for this, but I believe the "correct" solution is to simply upgrade your flutter tooling.  Each version of flutter will provide suitable values for min and target SDK versions.  For example, if you build using the latest version of flutter right now, it will set targetSdkVersion to 34, as required by Google Play.
